# How do I create storage account and linked services together using ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I actually tried creating it but as it encountered errors. I assumed it can't be done. As to create linked services we need storage account key. I'm not sure if I can get the account key directly.

Comment: Let me know if both linked services and storage account can be created using a single template.

Comment: What services are you trying to link with? Can you provide more specific details?

Answer (score 0):

You van use the [listkeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions#listkeys) function to get the keys created for a storage account in your template. You can then use those keys to link to the storage account in another resource in your template. Make sure to set `dependsOn` and reference the storage account for that resource.

Comment: {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
 "parameters" : {
    "storageAccountName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Storage Account Name"
      }
    }
 }, 
"resources": [
  {
    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
    "name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
    "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "properties": {
      "accountType": "Standard_LRS"
    }
 }
]
}

Comment: within the same template how do I fetch account key from storage account resource and pass it to linked service resource.... can u help me here?

Comment: Take a look at this gallery sample https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/052db5feeba11f85d57f170d8202123511f72044/201-web-app-blob-connection, it shows you how to connect a blob storage to a web app, all within the same template. There are several gallery samples that shows connecting a storage account to various other resources within one deployment template.

Comment: "Input_StorageAccounts_Keys": {"value": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0]).keys[0].value]"

Answer (score 0):

As yoape mentioned that we could use [listkey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions#listkeys) function to get the keys.
I wrote a demo about how to config Dynamic connectionstring in another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41458346/arm-template-json-dynamic-connectionstring), more detail info please refer to it.